# What's the point of creating a user in order to access the DB located at SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string

So far, after creating DB with all the schema, all I have done so for was accessing them (tables) by reference through **ConnectionStrings**.

Now, twice, I've read that it's better to create a DB user and access the DB trhough that user by including him in the c**onnectionString**.

I'd like to know why so?

Thank for helping

Comment: For security reasons ? say someone manages to manipulate the data and run arbitrary commands on the sql server.. wouldn't you prefer that he/she has limited permissions on the sql server so that he/she cannot take over the system ?

Comment: Could "Security" be a reason?

Comment: So if security is the only reason, can I bypass that (user) during development stage? and comeback to that at the production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this if you wish to connect as a specific user, rather than (for example) just using the context of the current user which your application is running under.  However, if you use SQL Server authentication (i.e. username and password), you'd need to provide that password in the connection string, which is something of a security problem.

If the application has a group of anonymous users (or manages users/passwords itself) then its better to use a Windows login and run the application under a service account (which has minimal required access to the database).

If you're running an interactive application on the desktop, you should let those users connect to SQL server in their own context, by adding them to SQL Server with the required rights (e.g. db read/write , remove any higher functions).  Obviously you would use groups to make administration simpler rather than adding individual users.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't that clear.  It seems that you're asking if it is better to use windows security ("Integrated Security=SSPI" in the connection string) or a username/password ("User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;").

Its always better to use windows security.  Having login information within the connection string is a security risk.  Its in cleartext (unless you take some complicated steps to secure that section), and is sent across the wire as cleartext unless you set up a trusted connection between application and server.

Is it better to "create a db user and access the db trhough that user by including him in the connection string?"  No.  Its better to create a sql server login for user's windows identities and let them use those credentials to access the server.